# "Shared" test setup (ClassInitialize) in MSTest using base class inheritance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Having problems executing my test suite (using ReSharper), it looks as though static result set clash when multiple test classes are run together, not a problem for a separate run. the structure, in essence is similar to this:

```
public class TestBase
{
    protected static Sum Target;

    protected static void Init(int a, int b)
    {
        Target = new Sum(a, b);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClass1 : TestBase
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Setup(TestContext context) { Init(1, 2); }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(3, Target.Result);
    }      
    ... // plus around 20 tests
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClass2 : TestBase
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Setup(TestContext context) { Init(3, 4); }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(7, Target.Result);  // failed. Expected:<7>. Actual:<3>
    }
    ... // plus around 20 tests
}
```

I understand this is due to my poor usage of static variables and would appreciator any good suggestions on how to structure this better, assuming I have around 20 unit tests in each Test Class and test setup is way more complicated than the above illustration.

Comment: You understand that the problem is due to poor usage/design with static variables but are unwilling to fix the problem and instead want us to come up with a way to work around the symptoms. Not much else can be suggested. That is the nature of OOP and static variables.

Comment: thanks for your comment. actually i was hoping for a workaround, similar to NUnit's non-static `OneTimeSetUp`

Comment: That's what `TestInitialize` attribute is the equivalent of!

Comment: sorry, i meant `OneTimeSetUp`

Comment: Are you actively using the `TestContext` in each test?

Comment: ok, looks as though by moving the `Target` field to inside the test classes solves the problem.

Comment: @toadflakz not at all, but the test setup takes too long to afford running for each test

Answer (score 1):

You could easily solve this by removing `static` and by changing `ClassInitialize` to `TestInitialize`.

```
public class TestBase
{
    protected Sum Target;

    protected void Init(int a, int b)
    {
        Target = new Sum(a, b);
    }
}
```

Removing `static` makes the `Target` field local to the Test1 and Test2 class definitions.
Changing `ClassInitialize` to `TestInitialize` means that the value of `Target` is refreshed before each `TestMethod` is run rather than when the class is first instantiated.

Comment: sorry, not viable. see edit